# Формат даты и его преобразование

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql

### Как преобразовать формат даты из YYYY:mm:dd в другие, напр в dd:mm:yyyy на c# в проге или на сервере?

```
писал
select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 105)
менял язык, т.к. пишут в разн странах разн отобр даты
set language british
писал
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
после перезапустил....
На счёт стринга, да тупанул....но это не помогло, сервер ждёт формат месяц-день-год а я даю день месяц год, (а при отображении в виде год-мес-число в менедж студии)...и если я даю например 12.12.2012 то всё ок (якобы) а если 13.12.2012 то он первым воспринимает месяц...и всё(((((
Менять в проге.чтоб переводила в этот дыбильный формат....а потом опять,чтоб отобразить-не хочется....Как можно на сервере это изменить?
Вообщем я не знаю...просмотрел всё....не работает....может ктото знает, что не так?
.
.
.
.
Есть....сделал
http://hashcode.ru/questions/75572
[кому интересно прогуглите языки в базах данных]
Спасибо renegator
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Где-то так

```
string datestr = "2008:06:11";
string formatsrc  = "yyyy:MM:dd";
string formatdst  = "dd:MM:yyyy";

DateToime result = DateTime.ParseExact(datestr, formatsrc, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(formatdst));
```

Comment: не работает...
хотя подкл ещё
using System;
using System.Globalization;

Comment: DateToime поменял на DateTime всёравно.....

Comment: Не знаю, как и что вы там подключали (вы всё верно сделали), но пример целиком и полностью рабочий.

Comment: Да....я проверил....это работает...
Я беру в значение datestr вставляю radDatePicker5.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim(); //(Выпадающий список с выбором даты)...но он,хоть и выбирает только дату...притуливает туда ещё время типf 01.11.2011 00:00:00, а этот шаблон не понимает этого....я взял вместо формата formatsrc взял написал -"yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss" а formatdst оставил тем же/ но не работает...над result ом пишет String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: А вообще не знаете возможно ли в MSSQL сервере поменять формат из год-мес-число на число-мес-год, а то получ както по дыбильному все значения вносятся в одном формате, причём если число до 12(т.е. он понимает месяц) то данные вносятся, иначе ошибка....а когда читаю эти данные-получаю винегрет....

Comment: А зачем у DatePicker брать значение в виде ToString() если можно напрямую DateTime взять?